# Problems with format specifiers

Tags: c, windows

I don't understand the meaning of the numbers in declarations like %02lu.
What does it happen to a lu type number if I write it only by %lu? I'm writing such number on a file. This format is used in my code to write a long long int on a file using DBGPRINT

Comment: Those aren't declarations.  They're format specifiers.  Did you spend any time looking at the documentation for `printf`?

Comment: `lu` is the format for a `unsigned long`, and `02` means that if the number is less than 2 digits ten pad it with leading `0`s.

Comment: About the edit: `%lu` is for `long unsigned int` and `%lld` is for `long long int`. Please read the documentation which was written just for you!

Comment: Microsoft's page about [`dbgprint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-dbgprint) says: The Format string supports most of the printf-style [format specification fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions).

Comment: thanks to you all, it came out that i knew the right things because i read those things on the page sent by @Wheather Vane. My doubt was born because the written file has a corresponding number of 11 digits, so i wasn't sure about the reason why i should specify 02 in the format specifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type "`man printf`" into a search engine, the first hit should be [a Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html). It says:

> 0      The value should be zero padded.  For d, i, o, u, x, X, a,
> A, e, E, f, F, g, and G conversions, the converted value
> is padded on the left with zeros rather than blanks.  If
> the 0 and - flags both appear, the 0 flag is ignored.  If
> a precision is given with a numeric conversion (d, i, o,
> u, x, and X), the 0 flag is ignored.  For other
> conversions, the behavior is undefined.

So that tells you that the first `0` is for zero-padding values that are shorter than their field width.

Then we have, a bit further down on the manual page:

> **Field width**
> An optional decimal digit string (with nonzero first digit)
> specifying a minimum field width.  If the converted value has
> fewer characters than the field width, it will be padded with
> spaces on the left (or right, if the left-adjustment flag has
> been given).  [...]

So, `%02ld` is a conversion specifier that converts a long integer to decimal form, while making sure that any values that need fewer than 2 characters are zero-padded.